# вылезает ui-select, при выборе, за границы ячейки таблицы

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass

Есть таблица, в ней используются разные поля, в основном input, но также есть ui-select, для выбора из массива строк-вариантов. Проблема возникла в том что если выбранная строка очень длинная - то растягивается ячейка  на длину этой строки. Пробовал устанавливать ширину

```
.ui-select {
  width: 100px;
}

.ui-select-match {
  width: 100px;
}
```

но выходит что в таком случае я ограничиваюсь фиксированной шириной, вне зависимости от размера шапки таблицы.. Обычно ширина td равна ширине th шапки, можно как то ограничить данный селект, чтобы он был по размеру как размер шапки данного столбца? [пример плнкр](https://plnkr.co/edit/lodWuf4HjzX2uymaO2Al?p=preview)

Comment: ну можно использовать `mаx-width`, `min-width` для целей ограничения.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте свойство

```
max-width: 100px;
```